# Unable to create docker-machine with vmwarefusion driver on OSX

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine, vmware-fusion

I am running VMWare Fusion Version 11.5.3 (15870345) and docker-machine version 0.16.2, build bd45ab1.  When I go to create a docker with this:

```
docker-machine -D create -d vmwarefusion osxdocker
```

I get this error:

```
(osxdocker) DBG | Creating Tar key bundle...
(osxdocker) DBG | executing: /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public/vmrun -gu docker -gp tcuser directoryExistsInGuest /Users/ehc/.docker/machine/machines/osxdocker/osxdocker.vmx /var/lib/boot2docker
(osxdocker) DBG | executing: /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public/vmrun -gu docker -gp tcuser CopyFileFromHostToGuest /Users/ehc/.docker/machine/machines/osxdocker/osxdocker.vmx /Users/ehc/.docker/machine/machines/osxdocker/userdata.tar /home/docker/userdata.tar
(osxdocker) DBG | executing: /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public/vmrun -gu docker -gp tcuser runScriptInGuest /Users/ehc/.docker/machine/machines/osxdocker/osxdocker.vmx /bin/sh sudo sh -c "tar xvf /home/docker/userdata.tar -C /home/docker > /var/log/userdata.log 2>&1 && chown -R docker:staff /home/docker"
(osxdocker) DBG | executing: /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public/vmrun -gu docker -gp tcuser runScriptInGuest /Users/ehc/.docker/machine/machines/osxdocker/osxdocker.vmx /bin/sh sudo /bin/mv /home/docker/userdata.tar /var/lib/boot2docker/userdata.tar
(osxdocker) DBG | executing: /Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public/vmrun -gu docker -gp tcuser enableSharedFolders /Users/ehc/.docker/machine/machines/osxdocker/osxdocker.vmx
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 255
notifying bugsnag: [Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: exit status 255]
```

I am a bit lost on what the problem is, any suggestions?

Comment: Any solutions ?

Comment: Nope, I stopped trying to run it in Fusion and just used Docker and alll is well.